# Language changed after getting data from web server(XML data)

Tags: ios, xml

I am stuck in finding a way to resolve below issue:
I am using a web server to get xml data. I f we open the link on browse the data looks in Korean language, when I get that data in xcode's console, I get some other unknown representation of this data, and when I run the application on iPad, I get other different representation.

Can any one please suggest how can I overcome with this problem as it took much time in searching but I have'nt found any solution yet.

Comment: You may want to add the specifics of the request-response that you have tried.

Comment: It looks like XML parser is treating the XML as UTF8 encoded and decoding into wrong characters. XML content and some code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

@ Raj thanks for your suggestion, the problem was with encoding only. I used two different encoding types, when I changed it the data was coming as desired.